# IPtables configuration

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

First, i'm sorry for my english, not my first language.

I was wondering about IPtables. I read a lot of articles and posts about it, and thought i understood it at least a bit.

I spent hours trying every combinations of rules... What do you think ? Is it a good conifiguration, "secure" ?

Thanks in advance !

```
  #!/bin/bash
  #iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.test.rules

  iptables -F
  iptables -X
  iptables -t nat -F
  iptables -t nat -X
  iptables -t mangle -F
  iptables -t mangle -X
  iptables -P INPUT DROP
  iptables -P FORWARD DROP
  iptables -P OUTPUT DROP 


  # Autorise les connexions déjà établies et localhost              
  iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT      
  iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT     
  iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT                             
  #iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

 TOR
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT

  # ICMP (Ping)                                     
  iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP                     
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP

  # DNS                                         
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT                    
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT                    

  # HTTP                                            
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT                

  #HTTPS
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT                   



  # Mail SMTP 
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT  

#Transmission
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 51413 -j   
ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 51413 -j ACCEPT


  # NTP (horloge du serveur) 
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT   

  # On log les paquets en entrée.
  iptables -A INPUT -j LOG

# On log les paquets en sortie.
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG

  # On log les paquets forward.
  iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG                

  exit 0
```

Comment: Bump ? I'd like to know if any ameliorations are possible. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

First I like to mention that configuring the firewall on your local machine is not a must. If you aren't directly connected to the public internet (please don't do that), your home router/firewall provide a basic level of safety. Wich I don't mean that what you trying to do is completely pointless.  I only say don't go to far if you don't fully understand what you are doing.

Then for the IPtable rules. My advice is to start small and add rules step by step. Start for example with:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP 

# DNS                                         
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT                    
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# HTTP                                            
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT                

#HTTPS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 

#Allow servers to respond to the packets that are send by this device
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Test the rules by browsing to google.com. If that works add the rest of the rules step by step. That will be easier than trial and error on a bunch of rules.

I don't understand the idea of all the rules you're using. Some of them seems very strange. Rules based on tcp flags are high level stuff. For those, you need to know how  tcp/udp works. So leave them for now and focus on the others.

Also when you use a default DROP policy, There is no need to add extra DROP rules like you do for SSH. The less rules you use the easier is will be to understand.

One extra advice, it could be useful to Wireshark your traffic so you see what's happening. Just be aware that depending where Wireshark is looking, it will impact the traffic you will see. I just can't tell you for sure where Wireshark will capture the traffic. Maybe someone else can?

I hope this will help further. Otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Except, that what i did at first... But it didn't work ! So i took a look a some guides and made it working. But the problem is that the minimal code you just post doesn't work without the two line allowing state established... And i don't know what to make of that.

Comment: Yes, that's true. When you configure a default BLOCK policy in linux, it really means block everything. When you open a connection to a server, the server will send a response.  So without the 'established'-rule the responses wil be blocked. I adjusted the rules above, now it will work (I've tested it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. And that's still secure, with the lines established ? Also, it work without related ! Any reason why i should leave it anyway ?

Comment: And another question ! I read that for ip6tables, it was as simple as to copy my iptables rules and replace iptables by ip6tables. Except, when i do that msmtp  (smtp) doesn't work anymore. Iptables only, it does, iptables + ip6tables, it does not. What happened here ?

Comment: Yes, you can leave the 'related'-part from the rule. But it doesn't make you more secure. If you are really worried about security, you should take a look at additional things than only iptables. Know that layer 8 is always the most vulnerable.

Comment: One thing at a time. I did encryption, now i do iptables et ip6tables, and so on.

Comment: No idea for the ip6tables question ?

Comment: For IPv6, don't bother about that. You will probably never use it. It is mostly used by ISP's. Only in a few rare cases you will see it on a client device. So you can just block any IPv6 traffic. You could also disable it on the kernel if you like that.

Comment: Is it still the case ? I have some traffic on ipV6 it seems, and on the net, on test site, i have a "you are using ipv6". Disable ipV6 won't be a problem in this case ? Because it seems ip6tables really won't work.

Comment: I suggest you try it. Open your firewall for IPv6, Close it for IPv4 and see if you can still browse the internet.

Comment: SMTP is working with ip6tables (i had to accept imcpv6). Next question, back to iptables : can it be more secure ?